# How can I delete multiple entities with squeryl?

Tags: scala, squeryl

I know how to delete one entity, but when I try to delete list with entities:

```
val songs = List(song1, song2)
songsQuery.delete(songs)
```

I've got this:

```
Error:(77, 28) Cannot prove that com.logic.domain.entity.Song <:< org.squeryl.KeyedEntity[Iterable[com.logic.domain.entity.Song]].
   songsQuery.delete(songs)
              ^
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if you have a naming conflict between the `Table` named songs and the `List` named songs, or if that was just typed into the question. If so, that might be your issue.
You could just use `deleteWhere` here, and try something like: `songs.deleteWhere(s => s.id in songsList.map(_.id))` which would delete all entities where `id` is in the list of ids.

Comment: Yep, typo in question, sorry.